# Re-use the static method called in Blade template

Tags: laravel-4

Let's say I have a static method called Message::countNew() and that method used to count the new message from database.

And then, I want to display the number of new messages in 1 page twice.

```
<!-- On the top menu -->
<nav>{{ Message::countNew }} new message(s)</nav>

<!-- On the other location of page (still on the same page) -->
<div>You have {{ Message::countNew }} message(s)
```

If I do that, will Laravel call the static method (Message::countNew()) twice? Or does it have some sort of mechanism which maybe the second call will fetch the value from some kind of cache.

Or is there a best practice for this case?

Thanks!

Comment: This will cause two db requests. The best solution for this depends on what this view actually is... Is it displayed only from one controller action or is it more like a global thing?

Answer (score 0):

yes, it will execute the query twice. executing query is not duty of view layer.

you should execute your queries in controller or in a view composer.

there's a handy tool to trace how your laravel app works.

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar